# arrow icons not showing in ie8 due to after and before

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am using the arrow icon for tabs.
The orange arrow icon not showing up in the ie8 browsers...
the reason its now showing up is because i have used after and before in css...
can you guys tell me how to fix it for ie 8...
providing my code below...

http://jsfiddle.net/Dg5G2/14/

```
.playing-games **.soccer--image.soccer--active:before, .playing-games .soccer--image.soccer--active:after {**
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    margin-left: -13px;
    z-index: 3; }
```

Comment: try to use `::before`

Comment: Are you using the HTML5 doctype declaration `<!DOCTYPE html> ` as root?

Answer (score 0):

According to W3Schools:

For ::after to work in IE8, a  must be declared.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

For ::before to work in IE8, a  must be declared.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Do you use  with HTML5?

Comment: W3Schools is the worse resource ever better use developer.mozilla.org     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: What makes you say that? I for one love W3Schools. What's not to like about it?

Comment: have a look at this buddy http://www.w3fools.com/                         `W3Schools.com is not affiliated with the W3C in any way. Members of the W3C have asked W3Schools to explicitly disavow any connection in the past, and they have refused to do so...`